# DAYOFWEEK, Every Sunday

Tags: mysql

At work we need to produce a report that is 6 month old. Basically, from May 1st to Nov 1st, and the report has to be weekly based.  So far, I am only be able to do it one week at a time manually...

This is my code

```
SELECT displayname, capture_time,
       satisfied_load_time AS load_time,
       satisfied_response_time AS apdex_response_time

FROM   session_page_summary, page, apdex_value 

WHERE  displayname LIKE 'xyz%'    
      AND capture_time >= '2012-11-01 00:00:00' 
      AND capture_time <= '2012-11-07 00:00:00'    
      AND page.page_id = session_page_summary.page_id    
      AND page.page_id = apdex_value.page_id

GROUP BY displayname 
ORDER BY displayname
```

I stripped out some of the long code just to make it look slightly better.

The result is...

```
displayname  capture_time  loadtime  responsetime         
>xyz-a         11/7/2012     0.12       1.34
>xyz-b         11/7/2012     0.83       2.92
>xyz-c         11/7/2012     0.56       1.02
```

How can I get a result containing 6 months of data, something like this?

```
displayname  capture_time  loadtime  responsetime          
>xyz-a         11/7/2012     0.72       1.82
>xyz-b         11/15/2012    1.23       1.01
>xyz-c         11/22/2012    2.83       0.78
```

every 7 days I get the report.

Comment: @JeremySmyth FWIW, to my mind, a clear question typically includes a data set and a desired result, with a short explanation of how one would be derived from the other :-(

Answer (score 2):

The [`YEARWEEK`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek) function is probably what you need to group by week. It has a number of options to define how the week starts or what year it's classified in.

Your query would also benefit from using the `BETWEEN` operator. `x BETWEEN a AND b` is usually more efficient than `x > a AND x < b`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response tadman, however, I'm still fairly new at MySQL, I'm not sure about the syntax or how I should apply the YEARWEEK function, I believe I should put it in the SELECT Statement? Other than that, I am lost on how to proceed next.

Any pointers are appreciated!

Comment: It'd be something like `GROUP BY displayname, YEARWEEK(capture_time)`. How can you not be sure about the syntax when I linked you directly to the manual page entry? Please read the documentation first.

Comment: Thanks tadman, I wasn't aware of the YEARWEEK was linked, still trying to get used to format of the site, once again, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT displayname, capture_time,
satisfied_load_time AS load_time,
satisfied_response_time AS apdex_response_time
FROM   session_page_summary sps, page p, apdex_value av
WHERE  displayname LIKE 'xyz%'    
AND page.page_id = session_page_summary.page_id    
AND page.page_id = apdex_value.page_id
AND capture_time between '2012-11-01 00:00:00'AND '2012-11-07 00:00:00'    
GROUP BY displayname 
ORDER BY displayname
```

would be fine...

Comment: Hi Chella, I'm not sure how is this code different from mine, I apologize if I miss read it.